# Access to static variable is blocked

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2, ognl

In my Struts2 application, which involves some multi-threading, I get the following warning in my logs:

```
Access to static [private static final java.lang.String ...] is blocked!
```

What does this warning mean and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Outside the class, you cannot access private fields, Unless you use [java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static access is disabled by default. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39906977/573032) you can learn more about static accessors.

> OGNL allows execution of methods, but the static access is disabled by
>   default, so you cannot use static method in expressions. However, you
>   can teach OGNL which classes needs to access the static methods.